# Узнать текст ссылки по которой перешли на сайт

Tags: php, yii

я столкнулся с ситуацией, когда мне нужно узнать текст ссылки по которой перешли на мой сайт. У меня система такая, что при переходе на страницу с каким то функционалом просит авторизоваться сначала. А как выловить ту ссылку, по которой перешел юзер, чтобы в дальнейшем  редиректнуть после авторизации пользователя туда?

Comment: `Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer` что-то такое что ли?

Comment: а без использование yii?

Comment: тогда `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, но зачем тогда вы указали тэг `yii` ?

Comment: только вы учитывайте, что referer показывает ссылку откуда вы пришли, а не сам адрес ссылки по которой вы планируете перейти

Comment: ничего не понял. вам разве не надо вернуться туда, откуда пришли?